# Assigning a selected GridView value from SQL database to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to assign a value from a `GridView` control to a session variable. I have a SQL database with a table called `Computer_Cases`, and a column called `FormFactor`. My `GridView` is called GridView1 and the SqlDataSource is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HardwareConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Computer_Cases]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So obviously the `GridView` is just displaying everything from the cases table. I have selection enabled on the GridView control but I'm not sure how to actually save a value to a variable (e.g. `Session["Form_Factor_Selection_Variable"]`) when someone selects a row.  I'm trying to store the value of the `FormFactor` column for the selected row on the GridView control. The value will then be used on another page to display all motherboards (different table) whose form factor matches what was originally picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make use of the `GridView`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Here's an example.

```
void YourGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
  {
    GridViewRow row = YourGridView.SelectedRow;

    Session["Form_Factor_Selection_Variable"] = row.Cells[1].Text; // use the proper index for the cell that you want to save in session variable
  }
```

And, make sure the add the following property in markup code for your `GridView`

```
onselectedindexchanged="YourGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
```